# -e: command not found after SSH banner

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-server, ubuntu-20.04

Im getting below error printed while doing SSH to an ubuntu 20 server. no remote command is executed over ssh.

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~$ /usr/bin/ssh ubuntu@x.x.x.x
###############################################################
#                 Authorized access only!                     #
# Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized user!!! #
#         All actions Will be monitored and recorded          #
###############################################################
Last login: Thu Dec  8 05:58:57 2022 from x.x.x.x
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
-e: command not found
ubuntu@given-hostname:~$
```

Nothings on profile.d or ssh configs that I could find. Does anyone know the source to look for?

Answer (score 1):

When you login to remote server - the shell's log in script is executed (it's located in /home/user/ if you ssh to user@remote, i.e. on given-hostname->/home/ubuntu when ubuntu@given-hostname).

You can check what shell is executed for that user on remote host:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep user
$ user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/bin/bash
```

If it's bash, the ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile are executed (on remote host) on login and in your case some of these contain some command that produces "**-e: command not found**" - it's impossible to say which without looking into that script files. Check mentioned files for line(s) containing "-e".

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue if you use **-e** flag with **echo** in bash scripts and then call it with **sh**, it's for enabling interpretation of backslash escapes, like `echo -e "\e[0;32mThis text will be green.\e[0m"`, but this option is default in sh so it can't understand it.